# Customizing Popup Screen in Kivy 1.10.0

Tags: python, kivy

I'm currently trying to create a customized MessageBox in Python 3.6 using Kivy 1.10.0. I want to use it first as a MessageBox for error message when user entered incorrect username or password.
I'm getting an attribute error whenever I call the open function from CalcPopUp class using the nextScreen function from CalcRoot class.

This is the codes that I have:

class CalcRoot(BoxLayout):

```
def __init__(self,**kwargs):
    super(CalcRoot,self).__init__(**kwargs)
    self.calc_popup = CalcPopUp(**kwargs)

def nextScreen(self, next_screen):
    #I have some conditions inside this function which works fine
    CalcPopUp.open(self, "Incorrect Login", True)`
```

class CalcPopUp(Popup):

```
popup_message = ObjectProperty()
popup_button = ObjectProperty()

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(CalcPopUp,self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

def open(self, app_message, with_button=True):

    #if user selected the button attribute as true show button else remove
    if with_button:
        if self.popup_button in self.content.children:
            self.content.remove_widget(self.popup_button)
            # if answer is wrong, display button if not visible
    else:
        if self.popup_button not in self.content.children:
            self.content.add_widget(self.popup_button)

    #display text message
    self.message.text = app_message

    #display pop up
    super(CalcPopUp, self).open()
```

This is the error that I'm getting:

```
AttributeError: 'CalcRoot' object has no attribute 'popup_button'
```

This is the content of the kivy file associated to my screenpop:

```
<CalcPopUp>:
size_hint: .8, .4
title: "Message"
title_size: root.height *.05
auto_dismiss: False
separator_color: COLOR("#fcfc02") #yellow
popup_button: popup_button
popup_message: popup_message

BoxLayout:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    padding: root.width * .02, root.height * .02
    spacing: min(root.height, root.width) * .02
    Label:
        id: popup_message
        text: ""
        halign: 'left'
        font_size: root.height / 10
        center_y: .5
        markup: True
    Button:
        id: popup_button
        text: 'Ok'
        size_hint: 1, None
        height: root.height / 20
        on_release: root.dismiss()
```

Comment: I tried to change this part: `CalcPopUp.open(self, "Wrong", True)` to `CalcPopUp.open(CalcPopUp, "Wrong", True)` but now it gives me this error: ` AttributeError: 'kivy.properties.ObjectProperty' object has no attribute 'children'` I don't have an idea which one is wrong since on the tutorial that I followed everything is working fine.

Comment: Do you have `.kv` code associated with this? I only get this http://prntscr.com/fb23yy (a popup taking the whole screen without any tiltle or widgets) when I try to run your code, can't see the problem occur.

Comment: yes actually there is a kivy file. its too long thats why i didn't include it

Comment: I edited the question with the kivy file

Comment: I'm sorry, but what are you trying to achieve on lines 7 and 8 in the .kv file? It's telling me that `popup_button` is undefined which is reasonable. Can you tell me more about what you're trying to do here?

Comment: I'm planning to do a reusable messagebox function like what vb.net has since that's the first language that I learned. I want to have a function like CalcPopUp.open("incorrect login", True) which will show a messagebox with incorrect login and has a button since True is the second parameter.

Comment: popup_button: popup_button
popup_message: popup_message -- that part declares the button and the message widget using the id that i set for them from kivy so I can call it from the python file

Comment: I'm sorry I'm still a bit confused. Could you post a link to a screenshot of how you want it to look like? (in VB for example) A video or a few screenshots with comments would be even better. For now I got something like this http://prntscr.com/fbxw9f but I'm not sure if that's what you need. If it is, I'll post the whole answer.

Comment: yes that's what I want to do. what changes did you do to make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I did:

First of all, remove lines 7 and 8 in the .kv file. I'm not sure whether there is an indentation error in your original post, but here's how the .kv file should look now:

```
<CalcPopUp>:
    size_hint: .8, .4
    title: "Message"
    title_size: root.height *.05
    auto_dismiss: False

    BoxLayout: # this is indented to be inside CalcPopUp
        orientation: 'horizontal'
            ... # etc., no changes other than indentation...
```

I've changed the .py file structure quite a bit, take a look and tell me if there's anything I need to make explain:

```
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
from kivy.base import Builder


class CalcRoot(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CalcRoot, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def nextScreen(self, next_screen):
        # I have some conditions inside this function which works fine
        popup = CalcPopUp("Incorrect Login", True)
        popup.open()


class CalcPopUp(Popup):
    popup_message = ObjectProperty()
    popup_button = ObjectProperty()

    def __init__(self, app_message, with_button=True, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # if user selected the button attribute as true show button else remove
        if with_button:
            if self.popup_button in self.content.children:
                self.content.remove_widget(self.popup_button)
            # if answer is wrong, display button if not visible
        else:
            if self.popup_button not in self.content.children:
                self.content.add_widget(self.popup_button)

        # display text message
        self.ids.popup_message.text = app_message


Builder.load_file("calcpopup.kv")
root = CalcRoot()
root.nextScreen(next_screen=None)
runTouchApp(root)
```

Comment: Thanks man, it finally worked, I just want to be enlightened with the changes that you made. since you remove the open() function on the class CalcPopUp() but it still works, does it mean that the popup already has that built in function? and the lines 7 and 8 that we removed from the kivy file is the declaration of the widget using their ids to the screen on kivy, does it mean that its not necessary to declare them on the root level of the screen for me to access them from the python file?

Comment: Basically, you were trying to create one Popup and just keep it, changing the text each time there is an error. While that's logically correct, I prefer to just create a new popup every time one is needed. That's what happens in `def nextScreen` - I create a CalcPopUp and open it. I moved the parameters from your `def open` in CalcPopUp to the `__init__` so that's why I can do `CalcPopUp("Incorrect Login"). Another thing I changed - you were trying to do something like `self.popup_message.text ...`. You have to do `self.ids.popup_message` instead.